# Emacs -- jump paragraph up / down placing cursor on the first visual line

Tags: emacs

The jump paragraph up / down functions that are built-in to Emacs place the cursor *above* the first visual line of every paragraph.  The functions are significantly off when there are several blank lines between paragraphs.  I tried creating a macro that fixes the built-in behavior, but it was too slow to be useful.

Does anyone have a jump paragraph up / down function they would be willing to share that *always* places the cursor on the first visual line of every paragraph (even if there are several blank lines between paragraphs)?

Comment: Depending on how you look at it, this question is pretty subjective. I personally don't think so however a lot of people on here flag subjective questions at the drop of a hat so you may want to consider [editing it](http://superuser.com/posts/643618/edit).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion -- I will remove the subjective nature and just make it a feature request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** (December 8, 2013):  First rough draft.

**EDIT** (December 29, 2013):  Various improvements to the first draft previously posted, including, but not limited to dealing with special characters in `latex-mode`.

**EDIT** (March 3, 2014):  Created separate functions for the `modify-syntax-entry`.

**EDIT** (January 4, 2015):  Major rewrite without relying on modifying the syntax entries.  There is no longer a distinction whether the region is active.

```lisp
(defun lawlist-forward-paragraph ()
"http://superuser.com/a/685604/206164"
(interactive "^")
  (let ((opoint (point)))
    (skip-chars-forward "\s\t\n\r")
    (re-search-forward "^\n" nil t)
    (skip-chars-forward "\s\t\n\r")
    (when (= opoint (point))
      (goto-char (point-max)))) )

(defun lawlist-backward-paragraph ()
"http://superuser.com/a/685604/206164"
(interactive "^")
  (let ((opoint (point)))
    (skip-chars-backward "\s\t\n\r")
    (re-search-backward "^\n" nil t)
    (skip-chars-forward "\s\t\n\r")
    (when (<= opoint (point))
      (goto-char (point-min)))) )
```